# gevent install on x86_64 fails: "undefined symbol: evhttp_accept_socket"

Tags: python, libevent, gevent

I'm trying to install [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) on a fresh EC2 CentOS 5.3 **64-bit** system.

Since the libevent version available in yum was too old for another package (beanstalkd) I compiled/installed `libevent-1.4.13-stable` manually using the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
```

This is the output from installing gevent:

```
[gevent-0.12.2]# python setup.py build --libevent /usr/lib
Using libevent 1.4.13-stable: libevent.so
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Linking /usr/src/gevent-0.12.2/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/gevent/core.so to 
    /usr/src/gevent-0.12.2/gevent/core.so
[gevent-0.12.2]# cd /path/to/my/project
[project]# python myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 9, in <module>
    from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer as GeventServer
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from gevent.core import reinit
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/core.so: undefined symbol: evhttp_accept_socket
```

I've followed exactly the same steps on a local VirtualBox instance (32-bit) and I'm not seeing any errors.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest fix was to clone the [git repository](http://github.com/schmir/gevent), switch to the `wip-all` branch, and run `python setup.py build_libevent build install` which grabs & builds libevent statically against gevent:

```
# git clone http://github.com/schmir/gevent.git
# cd gevent
# git branch -a
* upstream
  origin/HEAD
  origin/close-socket-cancel-event
  origin/pywsgi-without-basehttpserver
  origin/upstream
  origin/wip-all
  origin/wip-setup-config
# git checkout origin/wip-all
# python setup.py build_libevent build install
```

More information [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gevent/browse_thread/thread/f490248a6e882a1).